# The `dot` in username within first 3 character preventing from comment replies?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies

The dot(`.`) in username within first 3 character preventing from comment replies?

Because I never got replies from anyone else using that feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ooops, I misspoke in this answer. Apologies.

This was a long-standing bug of too-strict matching on `@foo` --  it now uses the proper valid username character set to match, `[\w'\.\-]`.

Will be fixed in next deploy, within a few hours.

Comment: @Jeff: The underscore `_` is missing in your character set although it's valid in user names and appears to work just fine in comment notifications. I'm not sure, however, if I should add `_` or `\_` to your list.

Comment: @hendrik `\w` includes underscore. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, great, thanks a lot! I only looked at `man grep` on my linux console, where I didn't find that.

Answer (score 2):

I had [forgotten about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work#comment-97172), but yes, apparently either the FAQ or the implementation need updating.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *trailing* dots (though valid in a user name) are removed before matching.

Hence *Thanks, @name.* matches both `Name.` with the dot, and `Name` without the dot. <s>But: *@R.* is [too short](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75811/using-user-name-colon-to-refer-to-a-user-in-comments/75812#75812) to notify `R. Smith`.</s>

Comment: The last part is not true, `@R.` does very well match `R. Smith` (we obviously don't remove the trailing period if that would leave just one letter; that wouldn't make any sense). My point in [that comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75811/using-user-name-colon-to-refer-to-a-user-in-comments/75812#comment-184111) was just that it may not be the best idea to always strive for the shortest possible combination of letters to reply to someone.

Comment: oops, just realized I was digging up an ancient post... Deleting...