# Using "user name + colon" to refer to a user in comments

Tags: support, comments, stack-exchange, referrals

Does the following work when used in comments to refer to a specific user (say, xuser):

```
@xuser: blah blah blah...
```

Or should I just use separate punctuations?:

```
@xuser : blah blah blah...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that works. Since a colon is not a valid character in a username, the reply-to username in your example is considered to end on the "r".

Note that while a period *is* valid in usernames,

> Thanks, @xuser. That was helpful.

will also work, because a trailing period is removed from the mention (to accomodate this precise scenario). And since July 2014, [multiple trailing dots are removed too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235279/comment-directed-to-me-not-shown-in-inbox-or-responses/235328#235328).

Comment: Does this mean @R.. won't work? Or is it clever about that?

Comment: @marcog, see [The `dot` in username within first 3 character preventing from comment replies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913)

Comment: @marcog: We try to handle those edge cases as intuitively as possible. "@R.." will match a user called "R. Smith", if that's what you mean. It will also match a user called "R." (which isn't a legal new username anymore), and also matches "R..".

Comment: @Arjan: Note that I've rewritten a lot of the comment matching code, so take previous statements on edge case handling with a pinch of salt (in this case it's true, though).

Comment: The 11 points (which are in fact many more points) make a nice set for a unit test...? :-)

Comment: @Arjan: Re unit tests -- there's a bunch of them in this case :) And re R. Smith: As I said, the trailing period is removed, so we're looking for "R.", which is the first name of "R. Smith", so the two-character-first-name-matching holds. By the way: I tested the algorithm on a (few months old) copy of the Meta database; except for 8 users (who have no latin letters in their usernames), a reply with `"@" + username.Replace(" ", "")` always matched; with and without an additional period.

Comment: Lesson learned: You really shouldn't try to reply to "R. Smith" with "@R.". Use "@R.Smith".

Comment: Note that a single quote is valid in a display name too. Hence, `in @name's comment` fails to notify *name*. (But using `@O'Reilly` would work of course.)

Comment: @Arjan: Excellent point; I'll have a look at that.

Comment: No, @balpha, don't worry, [it's already official](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm afraid you'll have to edit again :) After the next build, these genitive constructs will be handled as well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to seperate any puntuation that follows the user's name.

See the FAQ question [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), specifically point 12 of the answer.