# Comment, directed to me, not shown in inbox or responses

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, global-inbox, comment-replies

I think I've detected a bug.

A user directed a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599352#comment38136972_24599352) to me yesterday, and the direction
(`@TomZych`) appears to be correct. However, it's not listed in my
inbox, nor in the list of responses on my user page.

This is a one-off thing. I've never noticed it happening before, and I
have no idea how I might reproduce it. On the other hand, the inbox and
list of responses are consistently not showing it, so it's reproducible
in that sense.

Could this have happened because there's a period directly after my
name? Commas and colons don't cause this problem, and according to [this
post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106339), periods are not allowed in usernames. If this is the reason, I
think it should not do that — it's unexpected behavior and I see no
upside.

Comment: One period is ignored, but he used three thus this is by design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are right about the problem here, but I'm not sure about it being "by design". Seems like we should be stripping three periods as well since it's a common enough rendition of an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). (Come to think of it, just stripping any number of periods seems safe. I'll look at this closer tomorrow.)

Comment: @AnnaLear cheers, I'm all for it, but also need to change [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) in such case.

Comment: @AnnaLear, thank you, it does seem like something that should be changed.

Comment: @Tom please accept Anna's answer instead of my own so I can delete it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I'll move the accept if you like, but I think your answer should stay to show context to those who read this later.

Comment: @Tom it will only be confusing, history is available via revisions of linked faq and recent feature changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the next build (rev. 2014.7.9.2360 here on meta, 2014.7.9.1696 elsewhere), we will ignore multiple periods at the end of a user mention when determining whether a notification should be generated.

Comment: Just to be sure, what about other characters which single instance of them is ignored e.g. `@AnnaLear,,,`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just the periods + whatever used to work already before. `,,,` isn't a valid punctuation mark, so nope. (Strictly speaking, neither is `..` or `.....`, but if we're going to ignore more than one period, might as well ignore 'em all.)

Comment: Tempted to test it now by @Tom...... but still won't work as new build wasn't pushed yet. :)

Comment: Let's see if it's now notifying @Sha......

Comment: Yup, working like a charm.

Comment: @ShadowWizard A comma isn't a legal character in a user name.

Comment: @balpha didn't know that, thanks. Any list of illegal characters for user names?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The only legal non-letter/number characters are apostrophe, period, dash, underscore, and space.

Comment: @balpha thanks, how you detect what is a letter and what isn't? I recall names containing only blank space of some sort.