# Comment Information to be included on FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request

By this I mean information in regards to posting comments that directly pop up in users' inbox using @Username, and details of the correct format if the username is split up into 2 words like "Namep1 Namep2"

I've been using these sites for a number of months now and I am still unsure if I'm doing it correctly because I can't find reference to it anywhere on the site, but I was told by 1 user that's what it does and have seen a number of other users doing it too.

Since this is already a site feature I think it would be useful if it was referenced on the site and not just passed around by word of mouth, which could result in chinese whispers style passing of information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: hmm couldn't find that when I looked, I'll read it now and if it covers same stuff I'll delete this question

Comment: it's true that it's info covering what I asked but I'm asking for that info to be put on the FAQ since it's a main part of the site and otherwise hard to find.

Comment: Most of done the comment search on SO since repeating it now on both sites yeilds on meta the info on 3rd down the list and nothing on SO but still means it should be included on SO since I don't think meta gets any where near the same number of users as SO does or that new users would go to meta 1st to do the search.

Comment: What the heck are "chinese whispers"?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your post, but I _think_ [this is what you're looking for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies).

Comment: @PopularDemand must just be a reference local to people from england I'm guessing since it was a childrens game in which 1 kid would whisper something to another who would repeat it to another kid and round and round it would go till you got to the end and that person would say what he was told and almost always it would be vastly different to what was 1st whispered, and to clarify this is a feature request to which Baryy already linked where the info can be found and my request was for that info to be put on the FAQ of at least SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is (now) covered:

- in the "help" link under the "Add Comment" button
- in the editing help under [Comment Formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)