# Error message misrepresents available characters for display name

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names

As a test, I tried to edit a moderator diamond into my name and got this error message:

> #### Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - Display Name can only contain a-z, 0-9, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or number

I trusted what it said, until Michael Mrozek pointed out the comments of [Should psi be a reserved character for usernames to prevent impersonation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100223) that it isn't correct; for example, non-Latin letters are allowed. This message should be updated to correctly reflect what is allowed in a display name.

Comment: Pretty sure that adding a diamond to your name is considered **an abuse of the system**, and therefore the devs aren't all that interested in accommodating people who try to do this. The solution (as always) is: "don't do that".

Comment: @Cody A valid point, but that's not the only prohibited character, it was just the first one that it occurred to me to use to trigger the error. Less abusively, the slash character will also trigger it.

Comment: @CodyGray The point is that the message should read “Display name can only contain letters, digits, …” `Ψ` is a letter, `♦` isn't.

Comment: @Gilles: Ah yes, that's a good point... If I were you, I'd have proposed that alternate wording in an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Gilles That seems to cover most of the allowed characters. The only other I can find that isn't mentioned is the underscore `_`.

Comment: @Jeremy: [The underscore counts as a letter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#comment-268333).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Interesting, though I'd argue that the error message should be written in English, rather than in Unicode/regex/whatever.

Comment: @Jeremy: I do agree; as you see from the comments at that link, I didn't understand it either. By the way, I see that I now also got an answer to #3 of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104587/users-search-box-treats-underscores-as-wildcards-not-as-characters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, changing it to

> Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit

Comment: Underscores are also allowed.