# Users search box treats underscores as wildcards, not as characters

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, display-names

The underscore `_` is a valid character in user names, but when searching users on [stackoverflow.com/users](https://stackoverflow.com/users), it is treated as a *wildcard(!)*, not as a character. For example, when I type `w_of__` in the search box, then not only the user `shadow_of__soul` appears in the search results, but also, e.g, `BiscutWoofington`. The user `Wooff` is *not* shown, which makes sense since it's only 5 characters long and thus doesn't match the pattern `w?of??`.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Is the above behaviour a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?
2. Shouldn't `_` be treated as a normal character, and `?` be used as a wildcard instead?
3. What characters other than letters and digits are allowed in user names? So far I found spaces and `. - ' _`.

(Some testing indicates that underscores are treated just like letters and digits in comment notifications.)

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know we had wildcards.  Could we please keep them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We allow the following regex in search: `\w' \.\-` there was minor oversight that meant I did not disable the `_` wildcard that is passed in to the search `LIKE` clause.

I fixed that, it is way too non-intuitive to find. So now, there are no more wildcards for username search.

I dislike the idea of adding `*` and `?` wildcards. This feature is a bit dangerous and performance is somewhat random depending on the position of the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! However, it's a pity that there are no wildcards anymore. I don't care for `*`, but implementing `?` would be nice in my opinion.