# Underscores in search terms are escaped when searching for users

Tags: bug, users-page, underscore

When you [search for users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/) with an underscore in their name:

[image]

and then click on another tab, e.g. 'quarter', the underscore is 'escaped' (or in this case, 'imprisoned' is more appropriate) by square brackets:

[image]

Interestingly, this doesn't influence the search results, the `[]` seem to be ignored anyway.

Comment: Well, it used to be [worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104587/users-search-box-treats-underscores-as-wildcards-not-as-characters). :-)