# What characters are allowed for the display name?

Tags: support, display-names

I tried editing my display name and for some names it gives me this error:

> Display Name can only contain a-z, 0-9, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or number

That is clearly not the case, because it will take the following names:

- NullUserException -龍-
- NullUserException Ω
- NullUserException ఠ_ఠ
- NullUserException ಠ_ಠ
- NullUserException இ_இ

But it won't let me do:

- NullUserException  (╯°o°)╯
- NullUserException ٩๏̯͡๏)۶
- NullUserException ☜(ﾟヮﾟ☜)
- NullUserException อ้_อ้

So what's the regex used (assuming that's what's being used), so I can try out allowed names without actually changing it?

Comment: bug post: [Error message misrepresents available characters for display name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100256/error-message-misrepresents-available-characters-for-display-name)

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing my name to the guy flipping the table over and it didn't work for me either. If you can't have an ascii guy flipping a table over as your username what is the whole point of the site anyway?

Comment: I saw "NullUserException ヮﾟ" for your username when viewing this from the front page.

Comment: @Andrew It's because I've been messing with my display name

Comment: How did you manage to try out all the valid user names without running into the 30-day limit?

Comment: @Pekka - you can change it on each site and then copy the name to all the other sites.

Comment: @ChrisF yeah, I forgot. That was probably how he did it.

Comment: @Pekka It actually lets me try out a bunch of different display names. I think there's a kind of "grace period" where I can change the name as many times as I want

Comment: Try this one - ノ'o'ノ丄丄

Answer (score 19, accepted):

a-z includes unicode characters, the way we define it.

So essentially the [character set that maps to `\w`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax) in a .NET regex.

Comment: You have an... interesting... definition of `a-z`. May I suggest "alphanumeric characters", or "letters, numbers, or..."?

Comment: They made one of the classical Unicode Regex errors!!! Now we should try finding a numeric field and writing ৩০ for the age!!! (it's 30 in Bengali Digits. `\d` will conside them digits, `Int32.Parse` won't)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta [`status-completed`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100256/error-message-misrepresents-available-characters-for-display-name)

Comment: May I respectfully request that it follow the Unicode Consortium’s recommendation of the `\w` definition of word characters according to [Annex C of UTS #18 on Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties)?  Also, what is the length restriction in characters?