# Display Name in Local Language

Tags: discussion, display-names, localization

When I am searching my problem in Stack Overflow I saw display name in Chinese may be Korean I don't know.

[image: Snap shot]

So I also try to change my  display name in Nepali. I give my display name `श्री खनाल` but I got a error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Display Name can only
>   contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start
>   with a letter or digit

I know about the error.But my question is why I am unable to update my display name locally? I search but unable to find any thing about this. Am I missing some thing to understand?

Comment: Related if not dup: [What characters are allowed for the display name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106339/187824)

Comment: As explained in the linked post, the name you tried (in Hindi?) is not standard unicode while that other name is.

Comment: @Sha Its Devanagari Font not Hindi .Nepali language also use this font as well as Hindi language.

Comment: I also want to show my username in [Gujarati language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_language): `હિમ્સ૦૫૬` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the combining diacritical marks. As noted in [What characters are allowed for the display name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106339), the underlying test is

> the [character set that maps to \w in a .NET regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax).

From the linked page, this is

> Equivalent to the Unicode general categories `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]`

And there's the problem. Take for instance your surname, "Khanal", which is in fact

[KHA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0916/index.htm) [NA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0928/index.htm)+[vowel AA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/093e/index.htm) [LA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0932/index.htm)

The AA here is, in Unicode parlance, a **Spacing Combining Mark** in character class **`Mc`**.

**Character class `Mc` is NOT included in the .NET list of character classes accepted as "word characters".**

Thus, a string like खनल would *pass*, while add any vowel to any letter (eg your name, खनाल) and the test *fails*. "Shree" has even less chance, since it boils down to *four* Unicode characters, only *one* of which counts as a letter!

It's arguable where the bug is here - .NET or Stack Exchange, and some might say [using a Regex test to tell what is a valid name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888838) is wrong anyway, given all the corner cases.

But in any case, that's what's happening here. Try... having a name without any vowels? (this is a joke)

Comment: The joys of unicode. You'd think every glyth required to make a certain language would be all inside one class or another.

Comment: Can we get [tag:status-broken-by-design]?