# Allow @-notification by user ID in comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

Although I'm aware that [display names are not unique](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25404/254929), this is the first time I've come across a question answered by a user with the same display name as the OP ([here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/q/2935/1448)).

The problem this poses is that if I want leave a comment on the *answer* that notifies the *asker*, I have to play a guessing game:

[image]

There's no clear way for me to tell which Kareem is the real Kareem (short of [a certain arcane incantation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJO5HU_7_1w)) and I wouldn't want to mistakenly [shoot (an answer to) the wrong one](http://www.hulu.com/watch/1588/saturday-night-live-doppleganger).

This is confusing (if infrequent). I can't tell whether it actually breaks notifications but even if a comment using `@Kareem` would "correctly" notify both users, a system that allows arbitrary identifiers should be prepared to handle collisions a bit more gracefully. How many people read [the @replies FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/254929)? (More importantly, how many remember all of the implementation details?)

What I'd like to see is a slightly expanded notification syntax; for example, `@:` could allow notification by the user ID such that I would use `@:2561` to notify the OP in the above conversation.

Being able to type `@:` to show autocomplete options as `Kareem:2561` and `Kareem:1661` instead of just `Kareem` and `Kareem` would be a nice additional functionality.

I'm assuming here that an arbitrary display name could be `2561` or `user2561` but [could not start with a symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100256/254929). Another approach that avoids expanding the syntax would be to reserve display names of the format `^user\d+$` to avoid spoofing the "default" display name of another user and then allow `@`-notification by either of the current and default display names.

One additional benefit of this feature is that it would be much easier to distinguish when a reply is made to a deleted comment vs. a comment from a user whose display name had later changed. Again, this will be infrequent, and it relies on people using the feature - but if user2561 changes their display name on realizing there's an active user already going by "Kareem," the @reply by the other "Kareem" will start to look a bit schizophrenic. It's in just those cases where a user is most likely to want the alternative syntax that it might be expected to carry this added benefit.

Comment: As far as I understand, it doesn't matter which name you pick in the autocomplete. Either way, it will just insert the text "@Kareem" into the comment, and then it will notify users chosen by [this algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/134175).