# How can I reference a user whose name comprises more than one word?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

In some comments, I like to use @ to refer back to the user. That is easy with @amalloy, but I can't get @Arthur Ulfeldt to underline.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I get a two or greater word name to reference properly?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only reply to users that have commented on or edited the post. if Arthur Ulfeldt hasn't commented on or edited that post, such a reply is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go look at that post.

Answer (score 3):

As you're typing you should be shown a potential match with autocomplete that you can select. In most cases you'll find that spaces and certain characters are just removed. The following example shows me starting to mention the handle of `Anthony Pegram` which gets simplified to `AnthonyPegram`:

[image]

Comment: For really long names, just hit the TAB key as soon as the autocomplete shows the proper name.

Answer (score 2):

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> Spaces are removed *from the display names* for matching purposes. So to match Peter Smith you may use *@pet*, *@peter*, *@peters*, or *@petersmith*.  The last two are useful if Peter Jones is also participating, who can then be distinguished using *@peterj*. However, no spaces are allowed in the *@name* itself. Like to notify P Smith, one must use *@psm* or *@psmith*. (Here *@P Smith* would be handled as just *@P*, which is too short.) Single quotes, dots, dashes and underscores should [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913) be removed.